# Value representation theorem for preference relation

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations, economics

How can we prove the following:  if a relation $R$ is a weak order on a set $X$ and $X_\sim$ is finite, then there exist a function $v:X\to \mathbb{N}$, which is a value representation of preference relation $R$.

Here I know the construction of the function $v$ when the range is the set of real numbers (as $X_\sim$ is countable). But,I am confused  when the range of $v$ is the set of natural numbers.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Hint? I haven't checked the precise definitions for a long time, but isn't the set of equivalence classes just a finite chain? If so you can find a preference representation with integer values. Just list the classes in order.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker... yes, set of equivalence classes are finite i.e. countable in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Since the set of equivalence classes is finite chain, you can define a preference function by setting $f(x)$ to be the height of the class containing $x$.